# Como alterar conteúdo de uma página?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Estou tentando alterar alguns campos de um site, o que eu quero é abrir este site em meu endereço, só que com algum de seus conteúdos alterados.

Estou usando o `file_get_contents` pra abrir o site, mas enfrento dois problemas:

1. quando clico em um link dentro site, o mesmo é redirecionado para
   URL original.
2. não consigo fazer um 'clone' perfeito, pois o site tem muito
   conteúdo dentro de seus .js e css que são acessador internamente,
   exemplo: `background: url(.../.../s/images/ui/2011/cards-bg-RN.png)
   0 1px no-repeat;` o que busca na raiz do site original.

Queria saber se tem como usar o cURL ou outra variável para fazer a abertura do site e manipular determinados campos, sem que seja preciso eu salvar todos os arquivos .css e .js do site.

ps; estou estudando PHP à 3 meses, e isso é um projeto para apresentar em meu curso, mas já tentei de todas as formas que conheço e não consigo fazer isso de forma correta, utilizando um Regex.

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

;
$file = file_get_contents('https://urldosite.com/', false, $context);
echo $file
```

Pronto, eu fiz a página abrir, mas ele abre errado pois busca os .css dentro do meu servidor, e não no servidor de origem.
Minha principal dúvida é essa: teria como usar o file_get ou cURL pra abrir o site sem que ele busque os .css e .js em meu servidor? como se fosse um frame?
Manipular o conteúdo do site eu posso tentar me virar só!

Comment: Coloque na sua pergunta o código que você já fez.

Comment: Coloquei aí amigo.

Comment: Qual o objetivo Final, para que você quer fazer isso, pode explicar o fluxo resumidamente, assim talvez tenha uma solução alternativa. qual objetivo dessa navegação

Comment: Apenas modificar o conteúdo final do site original, alterar campos, para um projeto de amostra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta rápida é: Sim, você pode apontar para os CSS do servidor de origem sem precisar baixá-los.

Você precisará alterar o HTML baixado para apontar para o servidor, simples assim, ex:

de

```
<html>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css" />
..
```

para

```
<html>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://sitedeorigem.com/estilo.css" />
..
```

perceba que o que você tem a fazer é gerar uma API que coloque o domínio onde está o arquivo.

Infelizmente estou sem uma internet para montar em PHP mas o algoritmo seria algo como:

- Gerar um array com os caminhos existentes dos CSS
- Colocar o caminho do domínio (ou não) com base em se ele já tem ou não um domínio setado
- Use uma api de HTML parser (como a  [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm))para pegar os links CSS usando o seletor `link[rel=stylesheet]`

Após isso o código java que faria a substituição em Regex seria algo como:

```
String[] urls = new String[]{"estilo.css", "http://google.com.br/style.css"};

for(int i=0; i < urls.length; i++){
    if(!urls[i].matches("^http.*")){
        urls[i] = "http://siteorigem.com/" + urls[i];
    }
    System.out.println(urls[i]);
}
```

Se não me engano a função PHP equivalente á `matches` é a `preg_match`

fora isso desconheço solução cabível.